# styling issue how can I bring down the div id="space" off the ul tag?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrNaa/5/

in that link above I have added a map in the profile for member location but I would like to style a boder, or something that match the whole profile around the map so it doesn't look so plain plus I would like to know where it would be the best position in the profile to put this map. There will be some user description about where his live, biography, age, and all that common staff. how it would be better to place all this information so it all make sense? the picture, map, description and some comment form?

[Map](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrNaa/5/)

Profiles content

1.picture
 2.unordered list map
 3.description of the member"age, bio, location, hobbies etc"
 4. Comment form

Comment: you're going to need to re-word your question, or provide a screenshot of what you WANT it to look like.

Comment: the screenshot is in link above where is says Example Live, If you see the Pumpkin picture I want it below the Unordered list and the map

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrNaa/5/ in that link what would be the best place to put that map and how to style the boder so ti doesn't look so plain and have a little style around that matchs with the  rest of the profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using a different pattern. If you want the image to appear below the menu item, make it part of the menu item and position it relative to the LI parent:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="..">Pumpkin</a>
       <img src=".." />
   </li>
  ...
</ul>

ul li {
   position:relative;
   ... your styles ...
}

ul li img {
    position:absolute;
    top: ...px;
    left:0px;
}
```

You'll need to adjust the CSS to suit your layout, but this should get you started.

Comment: yes that's what I mean. what do you mean by different pattern? You mean to make it part of the ul the img and position it relative. You positioned it absolute right

Comment: Common sequences of code are called patterns. The pattern for a menu with sub-items is well-known.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrNaa/3/) what you meant? You need to tell the div to clear, not the ul.

Comment: I tried to accept it before but it didn't go through now it went thanks. Please look at the first post I have update it with a new question please let me know your opinion on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<div id="space">` is the element that needs clearing, and take the float off it.

Comment: Can you take a look at the first post please I have update the question